# IIS URL Rewrite for Reverse Proxying two servers

Tags: ajax, iis, mod-rewrite

I have two services hosted on following addresses in a remote server:

```
192.168.200.157:80/service1
192.168.200.157:7071/service2
```

I am requesting these services using AJAX requests. I have used ARR and URL Rewrite tools for cross domain AJAX requests. 
For that I have defined a rule in URL rewrite tool of IIS as follows:

```
<rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://192.168.200.157:/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Using this rule I am able to send cross domain requests to "service1" but the requests sent to  "service2" are giving "404 Not Found" error.

Firebug results also show that this rule is sending requests to service1, but unable to send requests to service2.

What kind of modifications or additions are required in the above rule to send requests to both services successfully?

Answer (score 0):

in the **action** node's **url** attribute in your code--notice the colon followed by the slash. This means there is no port indicated, so the default port 80 is used. Basically, these examples are equivalent (so get rid of the unnecessary colon):

```
http://test1/foo
http://test1:/foo
http://test1:80/foo
```

So...what this rule says is for all URL's (because the match node's **url** attribute will match all values), forward all requests to the port 80 indicated in the **action** node's **url** attribute value.

The **match url** value has to select only SOME requests (rather than ALL requests). And you'll need to write a second rule for the remaining requests. Your second rule might be your catch-all case, something like this will catch ALL requests that get that far:

```
<rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule2" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="(.*)" />
   <action type="Rewrite" url="http://192.168.200.157:7071/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```